# View master layout not found

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, laravel, view

I'm new in laravel. However, I'm created blade templates and integrate with my offline index webpage. It consists of signin.html and signout.html. So below is the structure way of managing my files:

```
-views 
--account
---signin.blade.php
---signup.blade.php
--includes
---head.blade.php
---footer.blade.php
--layouts
---master.blade.php
--home.blade.php
```

**Home.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master');
```

**Master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('includes.head');
</head>
<body class="bg-info">
    <!-- @include('includes.navigation'); -->

    <!-- @extends('account.signin'); -->

    <!-- @yield('content') -->      
     <!-- @yield('content') -->

    @include('includes.footer'); 
</body> 
</html>
```

The following two files will output the signin form in the page. I have no idea how they get into it. I didn't include anything. My public folder :

```
--assets
---css
---fonts
---images
---js
--index.php
--.htacess
```

**Index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->run();
$app->shutdown();
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', array (
 'as' => 'home',
 'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
));
```

**Home Controller**

```
public function home() {
    return View::make('home');
}
```

Now if I'm open-up my localhost, **View [includes.master] not found**. Perhaps my storage folder still contains the template codes, but I tried to delete, it keep generate a new one.

Another problem is when I adding @extends('includes.master') into signin.blade.php or singup.blade.php at the top. 
The localhost and localhost/account/signin or localhost/account/register will be **Internal Server Error: 500** .

Comment: Try to put @stop at the end of view where you extend layout if there is a section

Comment: And if you can Show us your routes and HomeController please

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius I did, but still didn't work.

Comment: so where is 'includes.master' included ? Because i cant find that in your code, but error said that [includes.master] not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Let me tell you something. What's the need to include your header from an external folder? Please follow this, your master layout should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  //put your codes here , not the include function
</head>
<body class="bg-info">
  @include('includes.navigation');

  @extends('account.signin');

  @yield('content')

  @include('includes.footer'); 
</body> 
</html>
```

`home.blade.php` should be like this:

```
@extends(layouts.master) 
@section('content')
 <p> Hello, this works </p>
@stop
```

Now let me if you need any further help.

Comment: View [includes.master] not found. (View: ..\laravel\app\views\account\signin.blade.php) (View: ..\laravel\app\views\account\signin.blade.php)

Comment: I have the previous codes in my app/storage folders. It consist all the previous codes that I have comment out right now.

Comment: check the file extensions and uppercasing issues. If you named Master.blade.php you can not call it as "master" .

Comment: Did you follow my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I follow your codes exactly and upper case and file extensions are working well. But error still occur.

Comment: Listen , The error should be View[layouts.master] not found. However , I had a mistake while typing the answer. The `home.blade.php` is now updated. Please re-check again. I think there is no problem should have.

Comment: The provided html should be into your layouts folder. That must work.

Answer (score 0):

Check `views` folder permissions. In my case there was a problem.

For this folder and all the files inside **permissions** should be **755**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, think that has something to do with blades caching of the view dir. I fixed it by **changing the @extends(example.master) to another template and then back to wanted path**. Worked without doing anything else, but as always first try `php artisan view:clear`.

Greets, Pat